# Creating class dependency diagram in Rider IDE

Tags: c#, .net, rider

Does that feature exist there? How is it able to be used? Rider official docs was useless for me within that issue.

Comment: I don't believe it has been ported from ReSharper to Rider yet. You can vote on the feature [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10171), along with the related [project dependency diagram](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-9869).

Comment: @JonathonChase is there not enough voices?

Comment: I couldn't say. I assume there are just other priorities for implementation at the moment that make diagrams a nice to have but not an immediate need.

Comment: Issues: [RIDER-10171](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10171) | [RIDER-4321](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4321) | [RIDER-11582](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-11582)

Comment: At least the [Project Dependency Diagram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Architecture__Project_Dependencies_Exploration.html) has been released since 2020.3.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE:**

Now the Project Diagram feature is fully supported in [Rider 2020.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/whatsnew/2020-3/#version-2020-3-project-dependency-diagram).

As for the class dependency feature, it is [still under development](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4321#focus=Comments-27-4218662.0-0).

**OLD ANSWER:**

posting this in case someone reached here while searching in google:

according to the jetbrains team:

> the “Project Diagram” feature, which builds a diagram of dependencies between projects in a solution, is ready for a private review in a custom build of Rider 2020.3

> Please, keep in mind that the 2020.3 branch is under active development now, and things may not work as expected, have bugs, and some plugins won't be compatible with such custom build

you can find [download links here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4321#focus=Comments-27-4372325.0-0)

Comment: And the current state of the class diagram: `Unfortunately, it's not planned for 2023.2 release. Our current plan is to return back to work on this in 2023.3`

Comment: No diagram for frontend code (Typescript) ?

Comment: @VictorZakharov check with JetBrains WebStorm, it *may* be supported there.

Answer (score 2):

No, to date it is unavailable. However it is under development, you can track it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4321