# How to find derived types in a referenced assembly?

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

In JetBrains Rider, there is an action to find derived symbols of a symbol. I would like to use it to explore a new library. For example, when I use a new class from the library, I want to see its derived classes.

Unfortunately, none of these find the derived types in an external assembly:

- Navigate > Implementation(s)
- Navigate > Derived Symbols
- Navigate > Type Hierarchy

But View > Quick Definition shows all of the types when cycling through the definitions. It does not show the hierarchy, so you do not see immediately, which type is derived from which.

How am I supposed to navigate library types and public APIs to get around a new library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695800/creating-class-dependency-diagram-in-rider-ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to navigate through an external library is to use [Rider's assembly explorer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Opening_Assembly_Files.html). Use double-click on a type to open it in the editor, and call Navigate -> Derived symbols action, which will show the list of derived symbols for a type under caret in the editor.

[image]